# Reflexivity in functional dependencies

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I'm taking a class on databases and I'm doing an assignment on functional dependencies. As an example of taking given dependencies and deriving other non-trivial dependencies using Armstrong's Axioms, the TA wrote this and I can't wrap my head around it.

Considering the relation R(c,p,h,s,e,n) and F the set of functional dependencies `{1. c->p, 2. hs->c, 3. hp->s, 4. ce->n, 5. he->s}`:

Iteration 1:

From F, we can build F1

```
6. hs->p (transitivity: 1+2)
7. hc->s (pseudo-transitive. 1+3)
8. hp->c
  1. hp->hs (reflexivity 3)
  2. hp->c (transitivity: 8.1+2)
9. he->c
  1. he->hs (reflexivity: 4)
  2. he->c (transitivity: 9.1+2)
```

I understand most of it fine except the cases where 'reflexivity' is used (using quotes because that's pretty far from the definition of reflexivity in my textbook). Can anyone tell me how that's reflexivity? Also, how do I know when an iteration is over? Couldn't you find an infinity of ways to rewrite functional dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the classical Armstrong’s Axioms (see for instance [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms)):

```
Reflexivity: If Y ⊆ X then X → Y
Augmentation: If X → Y then XZ → YZ for any Z
Transitivity: If X → Y and Y → Z, then X → Z
```

So in your example, to derive `hp → c` you can procede in the following way:

```
1. hp → s (given)
2. hp → hs (by augmentation of 1 adding h)
3. hs → c (given)
4. hp → c (by transitivity of 2 + 3)
```

Note that to produce `hp → hs` from `hp → s` the axiom to use is Augmentation, in which the role of `Z` is taken by `h`, and not Reflexivity, and this is the axiom to use also to derive `he → c` (by Reflexivity you can only derive, for instance, `hp → hp`, `hp → p`, `hp → h`).

You are also asking:

> How do I know when an iteration is over? Couldn't you find an infinity of ways to rewrite functional dependencies?

The Armstrong’s Axioms can be applied to a set of functional dependencies only a finite number of times to produce new functional dependencies. This is simple to show since the number of attributes is finite, and, given *n* attributes you can have at most 2<sup>*n*</sup> * 2<sup>*n*</sup> different functional dependencies (since you can have any subset of the attributes both on the left and the right part, of course including the trivial dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

A name doesn't tell you anything except what somebody decided to call something.

Trivial FD X -> X holds in any relation with the attributes in X. Ie a set of attributes in a relation functionally determines itself. That's reasonably called reflexive. It happens that it functionally determines *every* subset of itself. It happens "reflexivity" was chosen as the name for the more general rule & the more general rule was chosen as one of a set of sufficient but  non-redundant rules.

Armstrong's axioms have been shown to be sound & complete. Sound means they only generate implied FDs. Complete means that if you keep applying an axiom until you don't get any new FDs by applying any of them then you get all the FDs that can be derived from the original set, ie that also must hold when the original ones hold. Any textbook tells you that you can generate such a transitive closure of a set of FDs by doing just that.

There are also sound & complete axiom sets for FDs + MVDs. But there aren't for FDs + JDs.